# Hide specific columns in a doctrine2 query

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

When i'm retrieving the user entity from the database, the password attribute shows up. I want to specifically don't show some attributes from the table. Like the password. is there a configuration for this in doctrine2?

I'm using annotations. :)

Answer (score 1):

As nifr said, i selected what i really needed.
In DQL, if you select the data user.name, user.address, it will take out of the context of the join, and put the data at the end of the array. So, for this to be solved, and continue with the consistency of the JOINs, the solution was to make a PARTIAL. So the code was something like:

```
SELECT project, pm, pu, dfp, df, collection, partial admin.{id}, admetas, cm
```

Of course this is only the select statement, but with that, the admin.{id} sticks to the context and doesn't "jump out" of the array, when you do a getArrayResult();

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no "filter" to remove only certain properties when fetching.

Create a custom query inside your entity repository and fetch only the fields you really need:

**UserRepository**

```
public function findAllUserNamesAndAddresses()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
       ->select(array('user.name','user.address'))
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult()
   ;
}
```